# Как вырезать ссылку регулярным выражением?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

html code

```
<img src="/images/photos/profile/gradient.png" class="_53l"></div></div><div class="_53s fbPhotoCurationControlWrapper fbPhotoStarGridElement fbPhotoStarGridNonStarred _53s fbPhotoCurationControlWrapper" data-starred-src="http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/p417x417/424104_462592180467052_334726552_n.jpg" data-non-starred-src="http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/p206x206/424104_462592180467052_334726552_n.jpg" data-reorderid="462592180467052" data-fbid="462592180467052" id="u_jsonp_3_4" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 211px;"><a class="uiMediaThumb _6i9 uiMediaThumbMedium" href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=462592180467052&amp;set=pb.160420524017554.-2207520000.1358928023&amp;type=3&amp;src=http%3A%2F%2Fsphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash3%2F739991_462592180467052_334726552_o.jpg&amp;smallsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fsphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash4%2F424104_462592180467052_334726552_n.jpg&amp;size=1280%2C854" aria-label="Фото" id="pic_462592180467052" rel="theater" ajaxify="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=462592180467052&amp;set=pb.160420524017554.-2207520000.1358928023&amp;type=3&amp;src=http%3A%2F%2Fsphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash3%2F739991_462592180467052_334726552_o.jpg&amp;smallsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fsphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash4%2F424104_462592180467052_334726552_n.jpg&amp;size=1280%2C854&amp;theater"><div class="tagWrapper"><i style="background-image: url(http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/p206x206/424104_462592180467052_334726552_n.jpg);" class="uiMediaThumbImg">
```

Рег. выражение

```
/http:\/\/sphotos.+?\/.+?\/p206x206\/\d+_\d+_\d+_n\.jpg/g
```

отдает

```
http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/p417x417/424104_462592180467052_334726552_n.jpg" data-non-starred-src="http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/p206x206/424104_462592180467052_334726552_n.jpg
```

Как вырезать ?

http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/p206x206/424104_462592180467052_334726552_n.jpg

Comment: может так  

    #data-non-starred-src="(http:\/\/sphotos.+?\/.+?\/p206x206\/\d+_\d+_\d+_n\.jpg)"#g

Не знаю как в js, а перле потом можно использовать переменную типа $1 для обращения к найденной строке.

Comment: "data-non-starred-src="http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/p206x206/269437_463491857043751_448051827_n.jpg"" 
результат. Нужно саму ссылку вырезать, начиная с Http://

Comment: Оффтоп: В жизни каждого программиста есть моменты, когда он думает: "О! Я могу решить эту проблему с помощью регэкспов!" С этого момента у программиста уже две проблемы... 
По делу: Если использовать регэкспы принципиально, то может стоит попробовать сделать это двумя регэкспами? Так будет легче разбираться в коде, если вернётесь к нему позже. Если же использование регэкспов не принципиально, я бы посоветовал XPath.

Comment: @fori1ton баян. Продолжая оффтоп: поделитесь инфой, как сделать парсер без регулярных выражений.

Comment: @zenith в общем случае парсер без регэкспов не сделать не получится. В данном случае с XPath было бы проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю вам поможет [это](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/regexp-specials#nayti-vse-so-skobkami)

Приближённая  адаптация примера из справочника:

```
function lalala(html){
var re =  #data-non-starred-src="(http:\/\/sphotos.+?\/.+?\/p206x206\/\d+_\d+_\d+_n\.jpg)"#g
 var res
  while ( (res = re.exec(html)) != null) {
   alert("link to img: "+ res[1]);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ссылки на *jpg* можно и попроще вытаскивать:

```
http:[^'"]+.jpg
```

Comment: В общем виде -- да.  
Но в данном случае ТС хочет получить только ссылку на уменьшенное изображение.

Comment: Ну так, измените на _n\.jpg

Comment: @Кирилл Новгородцев не факт что всегда будет "_n.jpg".